# Access specific object from array of objets via json file in angular 6

Tags: json, angular6

I have a JSON object in my assets folder I am reading as below

data.json

```
[ 
{
 "modName":"deployment",
 "year":"1992",
  "description":"basic deployment"
},

{
 "modName":"Integration",
  "year":"1995",
  "description":"popular integration"
}
]
```

In my dataService.ts file my reading JSON object

```
getData(){
 return this.http.get('assests/data.json');
}

getDataInfo{
 return this.getData().subscribe(data=>{
 if(data!==undefined)
  for(let i in data){
   if(data[i].modName=='deployment'){
     return data[i];
  }
  }
 })
}
```

I am accessing this object in my main component
  let data = this.dataService.getDataInfo()

this is giving me a subscriber though I want a specific data object.How can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getData goes in service, getDataInfo goes in component and then in component you can create variable myDataInfo and just on line where you return data do this

```
this.myDataInfo = data[i]
```

OR

same as above with service and component method, but you can store your data to some variable eg. `this.myJsonData`

and then you can do something like this

```
get myDataInfo() {
    return this.myJsonData.filter((item) => item.modName=='deployment')[0]
}
```

and the you just can use that object in your template easy.

Comment: Thanks that helps :)